# TypeScript: Decorators for Function Expressions

Tags: typescript, decorator

I am trying to add a function decorator to a function expression.
The decorator works for function declarations but not for function expressions.

**Decorator**:

```
function track(val: string) {

    return function(_target: any, _key: string, descriptor: any)  {

        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
           Logger.log(val);
           originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
```

Function expression which I'm trying to annotate:
It will not work if I try to decorate like this:

```
const handleClick = @track('trackMe') (e) => { console.log(e) };
```

or this:

```
@trackMetric('sdf')
const handleClick = (e) => { console.log(e) };
```

I have **experimentalDecorators** flag on and targets **ES5**.

Comment: Right, as [stated in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html): "With the introduction of **Classes** in TypeScript and ES6, there now exist certain scenarios that require additional features to support annotating or modifying **classes** and **class members**. Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for **class** declarations and members.".  Only classes can be decorated.

Comment: Decorators for functions are currently not supported, but TS follows the ES decorators proposal which is work-in-progress, see https://github.com/iddan/proposal-function-expression-decorators/issues/3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can not decorate a function, you can ONLY decorate:

- Class constructors
- Class methods
- Class method parameters
- Class getters/setters
- Class properties

Comment: Why tho?  What's wrong with decorating functions or function parameters?

Comment: Typescript follows ECMAScript and it appears that function hoisting complicates things ... so thing is still discussed: https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method and decorate this method with your factory like this:

As such, the following steps are performed when evaluating multiple decorators on a single declaration in TypeScript:

The expressions for each decorator are evaluated top-to-bottom.
The results are then called as functions from bottom-to-top.
If we were to use decorator factories, we can observe this evaluation order with the following example:

```
function f() {
    console.log("f(): evaluated");
    return function (
            target,
            propertyKey: string,
            descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
        ) {
        console.log("f(): called");
    };
}

function g() {
    console.log("g(): evaluated");
    return function (
        target,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ) {
        console.log("g(): called");
    };
}

class C {
    @f()
    @g()
    method() {}
}
```

Which would print this output to the console:

---

You should read this: [Decorators in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)